# Fixing Laravel's NotFoundHttpException

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a few subpages in Laravel framework. All of them is working. (/about, /contact, /projects, etc.), but always when I want to navigate to some other subfolder named ex. /wordpress it gives me:  NotFoundHttpException error.

So I want only my subpages to work but not other subfolders in my domain. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

1. Not recommended:

   Put your subfolders on the public folder inside the Laravel app directory if you want to access them.
2. Recommended

   Configure subdomains